# Adding an existing package to existing Java Project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am trying to add a package from another java project into my current java project in Eclipse. I tried simply dragging the package files into the java project folder. When I looked for the package in eclipse it did not show up even after I refreshed the interface.

Is there something I am missing? It should be that easy right?

Comment: Ctrl+C/V? Do you want to add your just refer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, If you drag and drop the project/package, there are mainly three options available to choose. I think you chose to "link files and folders". You might want to choose "Copy files and folders" rather than other options to get those files and folders.

[image]

Comment: I will try that, but when I meant drag and drop I meant from the Windows explorer.

Comment: Ohh. You can try from the eclipse's Project Explorer. Its quite easy.

Comment: I tried what you recommended and it sort of worked but I am still getting the same issue. The project layout window on my left just shows 2 white empty packages where my files should be

Comment: yeah several times... nothing

Comment: If you make changes to the project's directory structure outside of Eclipse you'll need to manually refresh Eclipse - right click on the project and press `Refresh`.

Comment: ... I feel foolish. I found the problem. The files I am trying to import are .class files not .java files.